# Find the closest match within a separator split in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, split

I have a dict like this

```py
#: key: name, value: separator
namespaces = { 'INBOX.': '.', 
               'INBOX/Trash': '/', 
               'INBOX$Trash$Send': '$' }
```

If the user input is `INBOX.Trash` the match should be `INBOX/Trash`
If the user input is `INBOX.Trash123` the match should be `INBOX.`
If the user input is `INBOX.Trash.Foo` the match should be `INBOX/Trash`
If the user input is `INBOX.Foo` the match should be `INBOX.`
If the user input is `INBOX.Tras` the match should be `INBOX.`
(The separator of the user input is also known)

So i need to find the closest match within a separator split. Any ideas?

Comment: Please show us the code for your latest attempt and where you got stuck. See also: [ask] and [help/on-topic].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def closest_match(path):
    if len(path) >= 6:
        separator = path[5]
        split_path = path.split(separator)
    else:
        split_path = path
    
    namespaces = {'INBOX.': ['INBOX'],
                  'INBOX/Trash': ['INBOX', 'Trash'],
                  'INBOX$Trash$Send': ['INBOX', 'Trash', 'Send']}
    matches = [k for k, v in namespaces.items() if all(sub in split_path for sub in v)]
    return max(matches, key=len)

closest_match('INBOX.Trash123')
```

Comment: Thanks. `closest_match('INBOX.Trash123')` returns `INBOX/Trash` which is wrong. `INBOX.` would be right.

Comment: I edited to handle this case. Note, my code assumes that the separator is  at index 5 of the string, and that the same separator is used throughout the string